# FeedItem values to be displayed only when the createdbyid!=insertedbyid

Tags: apex, visualforce, feeditem

I have the following piece of code in my visualforce page

```
<apex:pageBlockTable value="{!AModel.RelFeedItems}" var="Feeds">
               <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Date</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Feeds.CreatedDate}" />
                </apex:column>
               <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Body</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputText value="{!Feeds.Body}" />
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">ModStamp</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Feeds.SystemModstamp}" rendered="insertedbyid!=createdbyid"/>**!--I want some thing like this--**
                </apex:column>
                <apex:column >
                    <apex:facet name="header">Inserted By Name</apex:facet>
                    <apex:outputField value="{!Feeds.InsertedBy.name}" />
                </apex:column>
          </apex:pageBlockTable>  
            </apex:pageBlock>
```

What i want is that the `modtamp` field to be displayed only when `insertedbyid!=createdbyid` otherwise it should display a null value.

Comment: I guess Inserted by Id and created by Id always be same user.. Any user case where these 2 values will be different ?

Comment: `rendered="{! feeds.insertedbyid!=feeds.createdbyid}"` You can try this.

Comment: @Ratan no, in my case it is different

Comment: Rimii any use case.. I love to hear you out?

Comment: @Ratan in my code, there are two separate set of users, one, for whom the feeditem is going to be inserted, another one is going to insert the feeditem on his behalf.. That is why in my code I am explicitly giving the permission to change the createdbyid. That is why the createdbyid and insertedbyid are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use IF condition inside the `rendered` attribute of `<apex:outputField`  to get the desired result.

```
<apex:outputField value="{!Feeds.SystemModstamp}" rendered = "{! If(insertedbyid!=createdbyid ,true,false) }"/>
```